# External registration of Tooling API custom models

Tags: gradle, gradle-tooling-api

Both provided in `samples/toolingApi/customModel` and [Feature Spotlight](https://gradle.org/blog/feature-spotlight-gradle-tooling-api/) examples of Gradle Tooling API custom model use plugin to register the model. However in order to apply the plugin it's necessary to either change `build.gradle` or use initialization scripts, which are supported by `GradleConnector` (yet).

How can I register a custom model within Tooling API itself, so my application can retrieve projects' information in a custom format without changing their `build.gradle` files? How can I get a reference to `ToolingModelBuilderRegistry` implementation in an application code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Init scripts are supported, they are just an argument like any other.

```
projectConnection.models(ModelType).withArguments('--init-script', pathToInitScript).get()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm failing to understand this line. Is `connection` an instance of `ProjectConnection`? Then in Java I would have to start with `connection.getModel(CustomModel.class)` before registering the model. Where does `withArguments()` belong to?

Comment: Seems you are referring to `withArguments()` of `BuildLauncher`. This can work, but then I have to parse an output of new plugin in order to retrieve the model. I still hope to use something like `CustomModel myModel = connection.getModel(CustomModel.class);` after registering `CustomModel.class` in Tooling API

Comment: You don't register `CustomModel`, you register `CustomModelImpl` in your init script.

I'm referring to `ModelBuilder#withArguments()`. You'll see if you paste the snippet above into your code.

Comment: Actually, this exact use case is explained in the blog post you linked: https://github.com/bmuschko/tooling-api-custom-model/blob/master/invocation/src/main/java/org/gradle/sample/toolingapi/ToolingApiRunner.java

Comment: Thanks! Building of that project was failing. I created a [PR](https://github.com/bmuschko/tooling-api-custom-model/pull/3) for that